# Antialiasing of text in Swing components , using JDK 7

Tags: java, swing

please tell me how to enable antialiasing for text in Swing components (using JDK 7), not overriding method paintComponent() parent class. To read about this topic , which says that for this method is used

```
putClientProperty(
     com.sun.java.swing.SwingUtilities2.aa_text_property_key, Boolean.TRUE);
```

requires a package com.sun.java.swing.SwingUtilities2, which is absent in the JDK older 5th version. Do not want to include in the project the outdated methods and libraries, could you please tell me what methods are used now for smoothing text of the components(similar putClientProperty()).

PLEASE DON'T WRITE about the use methods

```
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
     RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_On);
//or 

g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIAsing,
     RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALias_on);
```

because they do NOT WORK EVEN IF YOU OVERRIDE the paintComponent() parent class, the example below:

```
 JButton button = new JButton("Button X O") {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
         Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
         //g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
               //RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_On);
         g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, 
               RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIASING_ON);
         super.paintComponent(g2d);
         g2d.dispose();
    }
 };
```

It's not Work! Please, help.

Answer (score 3):

Global settings using system properties:

```
  System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings","on");
  System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true");
```

By the way, the override should work if you override `paint(Graphics g)` (which then paints the component, border **and children**) in the root container instead of `paintComponent(Graphics g)`.

Comment: Can you clarify what the second property does, or am I better off Googling. Testing with a project of mine, the first property activates AA, but the second doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!! And can you tell us how override the paint() on the root container? Tried to override the paint() using setRenderingHints() inside a class extends JButton(). Smoothing text not happened